# Как вывести listview в несколько столбов на больших экранах xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как выровнять или вывести правильно listview в несколько столбов на больших экранах?

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="data:Thread"> 
                <Grid MinHeight="75" MinWidth="500" Padding="10"
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{x:Bind Thread1.Short_Title}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind Arrival,Converter={StaticResource ThatsMyConverter}}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{x:Bind Duration,Converter={StaticResource SecondConvert}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind Departure,Converter={StaticResource ThatsMyConverter}}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
              Value="10,10,0,10" />
            </Style>

        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь, что `ListView` можно выводить в несколько столбцов. Используйте `GridView`, он будет адаптироваться к размеру экрана. Ну или заменяйте через `VisualStates` `ListView` на `GridView`.